# Problems with campaign member status field value

Tags: campaign, campaign-member

I'm trying to add campaign member status picklist value as per the document
[Add campaign member status value](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004216&type=1), followed all the steps this value is now available for that record only even this value is available in the backend, but whenever I'm trying to access this value on different campaign member which is associated with the different campaign this value is not available.

How we can access this value for all the campaign members if they are associated with different campaigns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Campaign Member Status values are configured *per campaign*. They are not global. Note from the linked documentation:

> At this time, this cannot be done for all campaigns at once, but instead has to be done individually on each campaign.  Customers that would like to be able to manage this for multiple campaigns at once should visit the IdeaExchange and promote the following idea: [Customizable Campaign Member Status Values Picklist](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br5dAAC)

Changes you make on any one Campaign's available status values have no effect on your other campaigns, which need to be configured individually.

There are third-party applications that will manage Campaign Status defaulting for you. I've used [this one](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005utCcEAI) (no affiliation with me) successfully in the past.